# Runnig computer with damaged battery

Tags: battery

I have DELL Inspiron 14. My laptop battery is damaged. It is not able to be charged. So, I run the computer with power connection. But, the light symbolic battery is red and blinking.

Currently, I have not enough money to replace the battery. Is there any problem if I continue running my laptop with power connection?

Answer (score 2):

Since the battery is dead, the computer itself has a protection from trying to charge it. Using the laptop with the power cord connected should be safe. If you want to be sure, that nothing happens, you could disconnect the battery and still run the computer with the power cord connected directly.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the battery should be disconnected